# Rendering partial view inside a view using AJAX

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to refresh a partial view inside of a view when a form is submitted. However, whenever I try it just renders the partial view as a normal view. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ChangeHeatName(string heatName, string updatedHeat)
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;
        HomeModel H = new HomeModel();
        H.ChangeHeatName(heatName, updatedHeat, user);
        ChemViewModel mySlagViewModel = new ChemViewModel();
        mySlagViewModel = H.QueryResults(heatName);

        return PartialView("PartialChemAnalysis", mySlagViewModel);
    }
```

Partial view form (contained in partial view, not main view):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeHeatName", "Home", new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "chemDiv" InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{
    <section>
        Heat Name:<input type="text" name="heatName" value="@Html.ValueFor(x => x.heatname)" style ="width:100px"/>
        Change to:<input type="text" name="updatedHeat" value="" style="width: 100px" />
        <input type="submit" name="ChangeHeatName" value="Change" />
    </section>
}
```

Index view where partial view is being rendered:

```
@if(ViewBag.SearchKey == null)
{
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name</h1>
            <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", "POST"))
{
<div class="searchField">
   <input type="text" class="search-query" name="heatSearch" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-success"  type="submit">Search</button>
    <br />
    @if (ViewBag.AverageSuccessful == true)
    {
        <input type="text" name="AvgConfirmation" class="search-query" value="Average Submitted Successfully" width:"400px" placeholder="Search" />
    }
</div>
}

@if(ViewBag.SearchKey != null)
{
    <div>
    <div id ="chemDiv">
    @Html.Action("PartialChemAnalysis", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
    </div>

    <div id ="slafDiv">
    @Html.Action("PartialSlagView", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
    </div>
    </div>

 }
```

Index controller that passes SearchKey:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string heatSearch)
    {
        ViewBag.SearchKey = heatSearch;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: The form is sending the request to the partial view action (`ChangeHeatName`). All this action returns is a partial view, that's why you can't see the full view. You should send the `GET` of the form to an action that returns a full view, and call the partial view from that view.

Comment: I would also add the InsertionMode.Replace as the next parameter of your ajaxoptions. So it would read: 

new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "chemDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}

Comment: @AndreCalil Thanks for the advice. I've tried calling the full view that renders the partial view. So my return statement looked like 

    return View("Index", heatName)

But it just took me back to that view without the partial view rendered.

Comment: @Danger_Fox Rendering the partial view should be done from within the _full_ view. At `Index`, somewhere, you must call `@Html.Partial("ChangeHeatName", data-to-changeheatname)`

Comment: @AndreCalil The last snippet of code in my question is where I call the partial view in the Index view. So when I first render the page based on what is passed it works fine. I'll update the question with the Index controller.

Comment: @Danger_Fox can you post your whole index view. The "chemDiv" snippet isnt enough to see how your index view is setup.

Comment: @DylanHayes Sure, I just updated the question with more

Comment: ok, i'm writing a novel here in the comments so I'll pop this out to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this because it's not an intuitive fix. Apparently there are issues with MVC 4 and jQuery 1.9.1 so to get this to work I had to change my reference to  jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this would fix the root of your issue with the code you've posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your ajax.beginform is in your partial view, that's all fine and dandy, but your partialview is not rendered inside your index, so really your never doing the ajax replace logic you're just calling a the action method and getting a full page refresh of the partial view.

here's what would work.

```
@if(ViewBag.SearchKey != null)
{
    <div>
        <div id ="chemDiv">
            @Html.Partial("ChangeHeatName")
        </div>

        <div id ="slafDiv">
            @Html.Action("PartialSlagView", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now your Ajax.Beginform is rendered in the index view, and when the button is clicked it will refresh.

Edit: you'll need to do something with `@Html.Action("PartialChemAnalysis", "Home", (string)ViewBag.SearchKey)` possibly stick it in your partial view, because everything in "chemDiv" will now be replaced upon update.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying `POST` in `Ajax.BeginForm()`. Try this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeHeatName", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "chemDiv" InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{...}
```

Also, stick a breakpoint on your controller action and step through it, see if it's actually hitting `return PartialView()` or skipping over it.